# Как сделать все объекты в линию

Tags: html, css

Я пытался это сделать множественными способами, но не получилось. Вот html код:

```html
<body>
  <div class="Hat">
    <h2>Logo</h2>
    <div class="Hot-P">
      <div class="Menu">
        <p class="Hot-P pp">Home</p>
        <p class="Hot-P pp1">Skils</p>
        <p class="Hot-P pp2">Project</p>
      </div>
      <div class="comunication">
        <button class="twitter">twitter</button>
        <button class="skipe">skipe</button>
        <button class="instagram">instagram</button>
        <button class="linkedin">linkedin</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Let's connect</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: о каких объектах речь?

Answer (score 1):

> Как сделать все объекты в линию?

Как вариант...

```css
.Hat,
.Hot-P {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 30px;
}

.Menu,
.comunication {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Hat">
    <h2>Logo</h2>
    <div class="Hot-P">
      <div class="Menu">
        <p class="Hot-P pp">Home</p>
        <p class="Hot-P pp1">Skils</p>
        <p class="Hot-P pp2">Project</p>
      </div>
      <div class="comunication">
        <button class="twitter">twitter</button>
        <button class="skipe">skipe</button>
        <button class="instagram">instagram</button>
        <button class="linkedin">linkedin</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Let's connect</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.Hat {
  width: 200px;
}

.Hot-P {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.Menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.comunication {
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Hat">
    <h2>Logo</h2>
    <div class="Hot-P">
      <div class="Menu">
        <p class="Hot-P pp">Home</p>
        <p class="Hot-P pp1">Skils</p>
        <p class="Hot-P pp2">Project</p>
      </div>
      <div class="comunication">
        <button class="twitter">twitter</button>
        <button class="skipe">skipe</button>
        <button class="instagram">instagram</button>
        <button class="linkedin">linkedin</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Let's connect</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```